# Is there any use of this mu function?

Tags: number-theory

Let $\nu(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ be the function that gives $0$ if $\sqrt{⌊x⌋}$ isn't irrational, $1$ if $\sqrt{⌊x⌋}$ is an irrational number, and $-1$ if $\sqrt{⌊x⌋}$ is a rational number other than $1$ times an irrational number. To understand more check this table:

```
   x     |           mu(⌊x⌋)
_________|____________________
   1     |              0
   2     |              1
   3     |              1
   4     |              0
   5     |              1
   6     |              1
   7     |              1
   8     |             -1
   9     |              0
  10     |              1
  11     |              1
```

Is there some use of such function? Does it have any connection in number theory?

Comment: I think what you mean is the function returns 1 if it's a pure surd and -1 if it is a mixed surd.

Comment: Anyway, is this function useful?

Comment: @user144437,it might help us to know the context behind this function,where you encountered it etc. .Also,why are you looking for the usefulness of a function?

Comment: What makes you interested in this function? Note that it can be written $(\mathbf 1-\mathbf 1_{Sq})(\mathbf1-2\mu^2)$. (The Greek letter $\nu$ is a 'nu', not a 'mu'.)

Comment: Since you are so interested in a function,why don't you try and figure out its properties?Why don't you try and see whether the function is multiplicative or not?As it currently stands,your question is rather ambiguous and perhaps not answerable.Having a specific question about this function will probably help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is really just distinguishing between three different categories of integer. The values of $1$, $0$ and $-1$ that you assign to these categories are entirely arbitrary, so what's of interest here is simply the categories themselves.

To make your definition more precise, $f(x)$ is:

1. $0$ if $\sqrt x$ is rational.
2. $1$ if $\sqrt x$ is irrational and cannot be written in the form $a\sqrt b$, $a$ and $b$ integers and $a>1$.
3. $-1$ if $\sqrt x$ is irrational and *can* be written in the proposed form.

These correspond exactly to three pairwise disjoint categories in which $x$ might lie:

1. $f(x)=0$ exactly when $x$ is a square number.
2. $f(x)=1$ exactly when $x$ is [square-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer).
3. $f(x)=-1$ exactly when $x$ is neither square nor square-free.

The categories themselves are of interest, as evidenced by the fact that we have a word for "square free" numbers, but assigning arbitrary values of $0$, $1$ and $-1$ to them serves no particular purpose as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Most of functions used in analytic number theory are multiplicative, that is, they satisfy the identity
$$f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$$
when $m$ and $n$ are coprime.  But $\nu(8)\nu(27)=(-1)(-1)=1$ and $\nu(216)=-1$.

I'm somewhat famirialized with analytic number theory and I don't know any use for this $\nu$ function, or special properties. Nevertheless, you can never say that something in mathematics is useless.